# getter and setter from database android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, getter-setter

I'm Trying To grab a complete row from a database table where I send the ID and receive  the complete details 
Here is My Database:

```
  public ArrayList<Item> GetProjectToMoreDetails(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase ();
    int ID = Integer.parseInt (id);
    Cursor cursor =  sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery ("select * from " + Projects_TABLE + " where " + PRO_ID + " = " + ID , null);

    ArrayList<Item> ProjectsArchive = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst ();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            Item data = new Item();
            data.setProjectName( cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( PRO_NAME )) );
            data.setPrice("$" + String.valueOf( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( PRO_GOAL )) ) );

            ProjectsArchive.add(data);
            cursor.moveToNext ();
        }
        cursor.close ();
    }else if (cursor == null){
        return null;
    }
    return ProjectsArchive;
}
```

Here are the Getter and setters Inside Item Class:

```
public String getProjectName() {
    return ProjectName;}
public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.ProjectName = projectName;}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;}
```

I'm Trying to call it like this but it keeps returning null From here

```
Item item = new Item();
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper( getActivity() );
    dataBaseHelper.GetProjectToMoreDetails( ProjectId );
    ProjectName.setText( item.getPrice() );
    ProjectPrice.setText( item.getPrice() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<Item> itemList = dataBaseHelper.GetProjectToMoreDetails( ProjectId );
for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++){
    ProjectName.setText( itemList.get(i).getPrice() );
    ProjectPrice.setText( itemList.get(i).getPrice() );
}
```

Check code snippet. You need to do like this.

Comment: Awesome, I thought when the database set values to the Item it becomes separate, then why it's still an array

Comment: your method is returning ArrayList of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your GetProjectToMoreDetails method with below code.

```
 public ArrayList<Item> GetProjectToMoreDetails(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase ();
        int ID = Integer.parseInt (id);
        Cursor cursor =  sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery ("select * from " + Projects_TABLE + " where " + PRO_ID + " = " + ID , null);

        ArrayList<Item> ProjectsArchive = new ArrayList<>();      
        if (m_cursor != null) {
          if (m_cursor.getCount() > 0 && m_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Item data = new Item();
                data.setProjectName( cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( PRO_NAME )) );
                data.setPrice("$" + String.valueOf( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( PRO_GOAL )) ) );        
                ProjectsArchive.add(data);
             }while (m_cursor.moveToNext());
          }              
          cursor.close ();            
        }else if (cursor == null){
            return null;
        }
        return ProjectsArchive;
    }
```

And fetch data in following way

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = dataBaseHelper.GetProjectToMoreDetails( ProjectId );
for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++){
    ProjectName.setText( itemList.get(i).getPrice() );
    ProjectPrice.setText( itemList.get(i).getPrice() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Item item = new Item();
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper( getActivity() );
    dataBaseHelper.GetProjectToMoreDetails( ProjectId );
    ProjectName.setText( item.getPrice() );
    ProjectPrice.setText( item.getPrice() );
```

with

```
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper( getActivity() );
    ArrayList<Item> ProjectsArchive=dataBaseHelper.GetProjectToMoreDetails( ProjectId );
    ProjectName.setText( ProjectsArchive.get(0).getProjectName() );
    ProjectPrice.setText( ProjectsArchive.get(0).getPrice() );
```

**Note**:-  This will only print values of the only first item, to get all values in a list you should use recyclerview and iterate ProjectsArchive in recycler adapter